# How do I capture server-side errors on Capybara Feature JS Tests using a lazy loader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

## Versions:

- Rails 5.0.2
- rspec 3.5.0
- rspec-rails 3.5.1
- capybara 2.12.1 (w/ chromedriver/selenium for JS tests)
- ruby 2.3.3
- gitlab-ci

## Past (and desired) Behavior

When I would encounter an error on a feature test, the stacktrace and error would be stored in the results on the console for my machine and our CI.

i.e. `undefined method '#dance' for nilClass at line 36 of app/models/dancer.rb`

## Current Behavior

We have recently updated the codebase to use "lazy-loading" (or server side loading) for particular datatables and particular views. This means that in a JS/feature test, if something in the view does not load correctly, instead of rendering an error we simply have a spinner that never stops spinning and a timeout error (or something not found).

Now, if I were working on a page in Development with a Rails server and something failed on the POST request for the lazy-loader, I could hop right over to my Terminal and check out the stack trace and what's going on.

How can I update my Rspec/Capybara tests to be more verbose and, when those server-side errors occur on a lazy-loader request, actually put that out to the test failures how it used to be?

Sincerely appreciate any help you can offer on this and more than happy to follow up with any other info you may need.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is being raised in the server then make sure you don't have any gems that catch the error and present nice pages (web-console, better-errors, etc) installed in the test environment, and make sure you have `Capybara.raise_server_errors = true` (it's the default so make sure you haven't set it to false).  With that configuration the next command Capybara tries to send to the driver should cause the error to be raised by Capybara.  If the error is being caught by something (like the gems mentioned above) and just logged then there is no way for Capybara to know about it.

Comment: thank you for your thoughts and feedback. I'm deploying these recommendations now and will let you know what I get...

Comment: Here's what I'm up against:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError:
        unexpected alert open: {Alert text : DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7}
```

So I will also try your changes alongside stopping Datatables from jumping over the top and rendering this error.